# How to create video captions (.srt) for a Facebook page using Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, srt

According to the Graph API v2.x, Facebook allows client applications to create captions for an existing video by uploading .srt files. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/video/captions/. Has anyone ever gotten this to work ?

My graph API *create captions* requests return with a 200 response and `{'success': True}`, but afterwards the Facebook video doesn't contain any captions. However, when I use the browser to upload the same .srt files, it works.

I'm using Python and the requests library to send my requests:

```
r = requests.post(url, files={"filename.en_US.srt": open(abspath, 'rb')})
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The python call is wrong, it should be:

```
r = requests.post(url, files={'captions_file': ("filename.en_US.srt":
                   open(abspath, 'rb'), "application/octet-stream"})
```

In that case the API returns the same response, but the captions **are** added to the video. See also https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/677584865713231/